# Continuous integration SaaS security considerations

Tags: web-application

How do CI SaaS products protect themselves from bad actors? When a CI server builds and tests arbitrary code, how can we be sure this code is not some sort of exploit? Are CI companies like Travis inherently flawed? I would imagine they have solved this apparent arbitrary code execution exploit, but I have no idea how they would go about doing that. Do they just allocate a VM to every user? If so, this seems like a bad option because of the VM overhead (not to mention the possibility of escaping the VM).

How do CI SaaS products deal with this?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on the company implementing it. Each vendor will have some security policies and guidelines they follow when setting up these systems. For SaaS these policies tend to be public to some extent as people will want to make sure they are in safe hands. Your best option of finding out how this works is to ask them directly if they can point you to some documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on the SaaS, but you might be asking the wrong question.  Are the problems mitigated by you self-hosting?  They probably become drastically worse.

CI is inherently problematic only when you forget what it is doing and fail to protect it correctly, regardless of whether or not it's SaaS or self-hosted.  If you are the target, and you have malicious code *build procedures* on an SaaS, you're probably lucky.  On success, they get pwned.  Not you.  If you have malicious code which was committed to your source repositories undetected, and you deploy that, you're probably in for some hurt.  Services are not going to detect that.

What are you protecting?  Your source code or your servers?  Define risk and determine watchguard procedures for source code to prevent malicious code from being introduced.